# Webhook / View Object Data from a Website (Wordpress)

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-object, json, webhooks

Is there a way to access records from a custom object and then put those records on a website without using API? Specifically, feed-like-RSS that could generate JSON/XML?

The CRM I'm working in does not (and will not) have an API-specific user. So, I'm trying to get a public feed from the CRM that I can style in the website.

Is there a secure way to do this without API? Maybe I'm thinking like how people used to get RSS feeds?

Comment: A webhook _is_ an API. Can you try [edit]ing to add some details about what you're trying to do or the restrictions you're working under?

Comment: @DavidReed Sorry about that. Added clarity. Trying to get something similar to an RSS to generate out of the CRM. Once generated, I would style it on the website.

Comment: Platform Events can be published from SFDC and the external website could subscribe with CometD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Force.com Site to expose a REST endpoint to the unauthenticated world. Simply create the Site in Salesforce Setup, then add the Apex class which implements the REST endpoint to the Profile for its Site Guest User. Custom Apex REST endpoints can return JSON data structures. If you really do want webhook-style authentication (a hashed secret), you can do that, although it's not best practice for accessing confidential data.

This is a high-risk implementation strategy. Your Apex must be extremely careful to sanitize inbound parameters and prevent SOQL injection attacks, because it is exposed to the world with no authentication of any kind.

Another approach is to make the homepage of this Force.com Site a Visualforce page which generates the markup your external system wishes to consume. The same security considerations apply.

### Further Comments

> The CRM I'm working in does not (and will not) have an API-specific user. So, I'm trying to get a public feed from the CRM that I can style in the website.

Your Salesforce org  doesn't *have* to have a single Integration User, although having one or more dedicated Integration Users in Salesforce is very much the best practice. You may Oauth into Salesforce as any active user. You'll want to use an account with minimal privileges.

> Is there a secure way to do this without API? Maybe I'm thinking like how people used to get RSS feeds?

I think there needs to be more conversation within this organization about what "secure" means. RSS feeds offer no authentication of any kind, and neither does the Site-based solution articulated above. That is, by definition, not secure.

To be clear, the only way to access data within Salesforce from an external source that is definitely secure is over an authenticated connection that correctly uses OAuth.